# iAd does not work in the other view

Tags: objective-c, iad

I have a little problem with iAd. I used the code shown below. It works well, but only at first View, when I switch to another View, iAd does not show (although I used the exact same code). Do you know where is the problem, please? Thank you for your help.

**The code that I used:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    _adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, 320, 50)];
    _adBanner.delegate = self;
}
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        if (_adBanner.superview == nil)
        {
            [self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
        }
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        _bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad");
    if (_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        _bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apple recommends to use single instance of BannerView instead of creating separate for each view, this might be problem in your case, have a look at sample app

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198

Also you can try this 

http://www.artmayes.name/the-iad-singleton/

Comment: Thank you, it was my problem ;-)